# AngularJS: ng-repeat doesn't refresh after updating array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using Ionic framework, and trying to display a list of "Card" elements using the following HTML code:

```
<div ng-repeat="case in cases">

    <div class="list card">

      <div class="item item-avatar">
        <button ng-click="rmpost(card.key)" style="background: transparent; border: none;"><i class="icon ion-close-round"></i></button><!--if (dataSnapshot.val().volunteer_email == firebase.auth().currentUser.email)-->
        <h2>{{card.volunteer_name}} ({{card.volunteer_email}})</h2>
        <p>{{card.title}} ({{card.creationdate}})</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item item-body">
        <img class="full-image" src={{card.snapshot}}>
        <p>{{card.message}}</p>
      </div>

    </div>

      </div>
```

This is my JS code used inside the controller for updating the cases array:

```
.controller('campaignslookCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $cordovaGeolocation, $state, $ionicPopup, Util)
        {
            $scope.reload = function()
            {
            $scope.reload();
            }

            $scope.rmpost = function(key)
            {
              alert("rmpost");
            }

            $scope.cases = [];

            //...

    firebase.database().ref('/cases')
        .on('child_added', function(dataSnapshot)
            {

            $scope.cases.push({key: dataSnapshot.key,
                                     volunteer_name: dataSnapshot.val().volunteer_name,
                                     volunteer_email: dataSnapshot.val().volunteer_email,
                                     title: dataSnapshot.val().title,
                                     creationdate: '',//(new Date(dataSnapshot.val().creationdate)).toString(),
                                     snapshot: dataSnapshot.val().snapshot,
                                     message: dataSnapshot.val().message});

});
//..
})
```

The $scope.cases got well displayed when being initialized to a constant value, but when being dynamically updated (via $push) nothing gets displayed.

Comment: It looks like your code is missing some crucial details. How is the `dataSnapshot` variable obtained?

Comment: Try using a `$watch` and refresh on change.

Comment: @JLRishe I updated the code. please help.

Comment: @VenomFangs could you please give me an example?

Comment: Where are you pushing the new object array? I made a simple example with a timeout. http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5652/

Comment: @Ervald Thank you for your helpful post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're updating your model outside of the angular *context*. The data has changed, but angular hasn't run it's own internal digest and hasn't been made aware that any changes have occurred within your model.

```
firebase.database().ref('/cases')
        .on('child_added', function(dataSnapshot) //FIREBASE EVENT NOT WITHIN ANGULAR CONTEXT
```

You need to use angular's `$scope.$apply` method.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

> $apply([exp]); $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular
>   from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM
>   events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). **Because we are**
>   **calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope**
>   **life cycle of exception handling, executing watches.**

Here's how to use `$scope.$apply` to get into a valid angular context and then update the data:

```
firebase.database().ref('/cases')
        .on('child_added', function(dataSnapshot)
            {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    //we are now within the angular context, so any updates to the model with be handled correctly
                    $scope.cases.push({key: dataSnapshot.key,
                                     volunteer_name: dataSnapshot.val().volunteer_name,
                                     volunteer_email: dataSnapshot.val().volunteer_email,
                                     title: dataSnapshot.val().title,
                                     creationdate: '',//(new Date(dataSnapshot.val().creationdate)).toString(),
                                     snapshot: dataSnapshot.val().snapshot,
                                     message: dataSnapshot.val().message});
                });
});
```

You could theoretically call `$scope.$digest` manually, but this isnt' recommended according to the angular docs. `$apply` forwards exceptions correctly and also allows watchers to be processed. It's generally better to use this method than handling `$digest` on your own.

> $digest(); Processes all of the watchers of the current scope and its
>   children. Because a watcher's listener can change the model, the
>   $digest() keeps calling the watchers until no more listeners are
>   firing. This means that it is possible to get into an infinite loop.
>   This function will throw 'Maximum iteration limit exceeded.' if the
>   number of iterations exceeds 10.
>
> **Usually, you don't call $digest() directly in controllers or in**
>   **directives. Instead, you should call $apply() (typically from within a**
>   **directive), which will force a $digest().**

Comment: After trying that: I'm getting blank data displayed instead of the data inside dataSnapshot.val().*.

Comment: @user6039980 should be working - any errors in your console?

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is perfect. I MindlessIy forgot to rename {{card.*}} to {{case.*}}, and that what caused the problem. Thanks a lot, that helps.

Comment: I just want to add that the button ng-click doesnt work.

Comment: @user6039980 glad to be of help! Unfortunately there's not enough information in your question to troubleshoot the ng-click problem. I'd suggest you open an additional question for this issue with additional details.

Comment: @user6039980 thanks for that. I'm assuming you probably need to `$state.reload` within the `onComplete` callback of the firebase `remove`. However, if that's not it, you'll need to open a separate question to keep this one on-topic. Also, people more familiar with firebase will be able to help you and provide thorough answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115135/discussion-between-user6039980-and-joel).

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `push` call in `$apply` method. Because you're adding in to your array item from the outside of angular scope (from the firebase callback).

Try the following:

```
...
firebase.database().ref('/cases')
        .on('child_added', function(dataSnapshot)
            {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.cases.push({key: dataSnapshot.key,
                                     volunteer_name: dataSnapshot.val().volunteer_name,
                                     volunteer_email: dataSnapshot.val().volunteer_email,
                                     title: dataSnapshot.val().title,
                                     creationdate: '',//(new Date(dataSnapshot.val().creationdate)).toString(),
                                     snapshot: dataSnapshot.val().snapshot,
                                     message: dataSnapshot.val().message});

                 });
             });
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Same answer that MaKCbIMKo.

I would add that there is this easier-to-read alternative :

```
$scope.cases.push({key: dataSnapshot.key,
                                 volunteer_name: dataSnapshot.val().volunteer_name,
                                 volunteer_email: dataSnapshot.val().volunteer_email,
                                 title: dataSnapshot.val().title,
                                 creationdate: '',//(new Date(dataSnapshot.val().creationdate)).toString(),
                                 snapshot: dataSnapshot.val().snapshot,
                                 message: dataSnapshot.val().message});

$scope.digest();
```